# Rotate Touch Input with touchscreen and/or touchpad

Tags: touchpad, touchscreen, orientation, rotate

So I just bought an Asus x202e, and have installed Xubuntu 13.04 on it. All working great.

However, I want to be able to rotate the screen from landscape to portrait, and still use the touch. When I currently rotate it, the touch doesn't correspond with it.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the end, I found out how to do it, although it's a little tricky. Still, if a non-mega-Geek like me can do it, I'm sure most of you can too! :)

Firstly, Go to Terminal, and type this to find the name of your touchscreen, and if you have one, your touchpad (say, if you have a laptop with a touchscreen):

```
xinput -list
```

The names should be pretty obvious for each.

Now, make two "shell scripts": these are little text documents that contain several commands, which are joined up in the document to be done together (effectively creating a little program). Make them using gedit, naming them "portrait.sh" and "landscape.sh" respectively. Save them in a new folder: /home/your username/Scripts/

For PORTRAIT, type this:

```
#!/bin/sh

#portrait (left)

xrandr -o left
xinput set-prop "Your Touchscreen's Name" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
xinput set-prop "Your Touchpad's name, if applicable" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Next, for LANDSCAPE:

```
#!/bin/sh

#landscape (normal)

xrandr -o normal
xinput set-prop "Your Touchscreen's Name" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
xinput set-prop "Your Touchpad's name, if applicable" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If you don't have a touchpad, you can leave out that line of code for each shell script.

Afterwards, I also made launchers to automatically run each shell script when I tapped on them (this is possible in Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, and many other Ubuntu flavours). To do so, go to your panel, right-click, click on "add to panel" (or equivalent, for all these subsequent commands, too), create a custom application launcher. For portrait's launcher, put in this command:

```
sh /home/username/Scripts/portrait
```

For landscape's launcher, put in this command:

```
sh /home/username/Scripts/landscape
```

I also made a "super+" keyboard shortcut for each of them. Find your "keyboard shortcuts" settings program (under Settings in many flavours, or just search for it). Effectively, do the same thing as you did with the panel launchers: Add a new keyboard shortcut, Name it Portrait and give it the command, "sh /home/username/Scripts/portrait", and do the equivalent for Landscape. Then give each of them a keyboard shortcut (say Super+P and Super+L respectively... although be aware Super+P is sometimes the standard keyboard shortcut for your Display Settings).

I STRONGLY recommend you make a keyboard shortcut for LANDSCAPE - that way, if your touch stops working, you can at least get out of Portrait, and back to Landscape successfully (VERY USEFUL).

For more information, go here. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1972447

(This link - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation - will also help you understand a little of the theory behind it...)

Comment: maybe you should accept your answer (and also expand it in case the links die in future?

Comment: Okay. :) how do I do that?

Comment: Click on the little grey tick, [like this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) and add some info so we can figure out what to do without visiting external links :)

Comment: Will that do..?

Comment: That's wonderful! +1 for your efforts :D

Comment: Note that for the landscape transformation, coordinates given are wrong. You're using the null matrix but you should use the identity matrix. I.e. `xinput set-prop $touchpad_name --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1`

Comment: for people that want to rotate to the right, the rotation matrix is `xinput set-prop $touchpad_name --type=float 150 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1`  (obs.: 150 is the code for rotation matrix property) and the `xrandr` command is `xrandr -o right`

Comment: Does anything like this exist for wayland? I'm having the exact same issue but I can't use commands like `xrandr` and `xinput` because I am on wayland (gnome-shell). I have debian 12

Answer (score 1):

I also wrote a little utility to handle this. Mine is a suite of lowly shell scripts, but they're interfaced and documented fairly well, so I'll add them to the list of solutions here.

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/kael-shipman/ks-utils/blob/v1.x/src/usr/local/bin/ks-rotate-display) (docs [here](https://github.com/kael-shipman/ks-utils/blob/v1.x/docs-src/ks-rotate-display/man1/ks-rotate-display.1.md)), and if you're on a Debian derivative, you can install them by adding my package repo [here](https://packages.kaelshipman.me/) and running `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ks-rotate-display`.

Comment: Are you still maintaining repository?  I could not install due to a bad/no public key plus the version is for bionic.

Comment: @TerenceGolightly, I do still maintain that repo. Strange that you're running into key issues. I assume you imported the key per step # 1 [here](https://packages.kaelshipman.me/)?. Can you post the specific error you're getting? Also regarding the distros, you're right, I haven't been good about publishing for other distros; however, almost all of the packages are just bash scripts and will work just fine on other distros, so you can feel free to use the bionic repo.

Comment: I attempted this: '  W: GPG error: https://packages.kaelshipman.me/public/deb bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8825EFF3280FDB58
E: The repository 'https://packages.kaelshipman.me/public/deb bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
'

Comment: @TerenceGolightly ok, I've just updated my keys and re-exported everything. I tested it in a docker container and it worked for me. Please try again and let me know if you still have trouble.

Comment: I tried it again; `wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kaelshipman.me-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.kaelshipman.me/kaelshipman.me-archive-keyring.gpg
--2022-11-02 16:47:20--  https://packages.kaelshipman.me/kaelshipman.me-archive-keyring.gpg
Resolving packages.kaelshipman.me (packages.kaelshipman.me)... 168.235.71.32
Connecting to packages.kaelshipman.me (packages.kaelshipman.me)|168.235.71.32|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2022-11-02 16:47:20 ERROR 404: Not Found.
`  Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I've built a little GUI that can do that. Completely based on those open source scripts. Have a look at **Screen Orientation Manager** [here](https://github.com/theGeekyLad/GtkExperiments).

Comment: Tx for your reply.  I'll try that when I am near my 2in1 machine.

Comment: apt errors out with your public key is unavailble: `W: GPG error: https://packages.kaelshipman.me/public/deb bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8825EFF3280FDB58
E: The repository 'https://packages.kaelshipman.me/public/deb bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`